# How many ways we can create web application in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have seen many examples where the @Controller annotation is used in web applications build using spring f/w.
Also, I have seen @RestController for creating a web application in spring.
And third what I usually refer to create web application is by specifying spring servlet in web.xml and create controller classes by implementing Controller interface or by extending either AbstractController.
What is the difference in these approaches? Are there any more approaches other than what I have mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Controller is typically used for a MVC Controller system and this allows you to return a model to your view from within the controller.

@RestController is typically used for RESTful web-services and this typically will output XML or JSON that you can unmarshal from POJOs with libraries or by overriding the ToString() method of the POJO.

In all instances (unless you are using Spring Boot) you will typically still use a web.xml. I prefer using the annotation approach (@Controller and/or @RestController) as it means less fiddling around with XML files.

I prefer not to use the third method you mentioned as it feels less flexible to me and more complicated.

Comment: Can we use the annotation **Controller**  with **RequestMapping** for creating RESTful web services?

Comment: Yes you can, I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above Answer, I would like to add some use cases of `@Controller` annotation that might be helpful to you.

1) multiple URL patterns can be handled by a single method.

```
@RequestMapping({"/hello", "/hi", "/greetings"})
```

2) Controller at the class and method level

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {


    @RequestMapping("/listUsers")
    public ModelAndView listUsers() {

    }

    @RequestMapping("/saveUser")
    public ModelAndView saveUser(User user) {

    }

    @RequestMapping("/deleteUser")
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(User user) {

    }
}
```

Note: If you want to use @Controller instead of @RestController you need to add @ResponseBody annotation like below:

```
@RequestMapping("admin/getVendorDetails")
    public @ResponseBody <Return Type> getVendorDetails(HttpServletRequest request){
...
}
```